# How do I return two lines of unions and a count for each row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, union

I'm trying to take 10 columns and put into one column, take 10 more different columns into a separate column and get a count for each unique couple in a third column.

So far I've got

```
UNION
(SELECT a_3 as x, a_4 as y FROM result)
....
UNION
(SELECT a_19 as x, a_20 as y FROM result)
```

This gives me a table as follows

```
| x | y |
---------
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 3 |
etc...
```

I want this, however I also want a third column counting how many times each row occurs, like below

```
| x | y |count|
---------------
| a | 1 | 10 |
| a | 2 | 3  |
| b | 1 | 6  |
| b | 3 | 2  |
etc...
```

I can also do:

```
select count(*) from (insert above union SQL)
```

but then I just get a total number for the table.

Thanks!

Comment: use group by clause after union query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your original table design is not normalized at all.

Instead of multiple union query, you can use `CROSS APPLY` with `Table Value Constructor` to simplify the query

```
select  x, y, count(*) as [count]
from    [result] t
        cross apply
        (
            values (a_1, a_2), (a_3, a_4), (a_5, a_6), 
                   . . . 
                   (a_19, a_20)
        ) v (x, y)
group by x, y
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a much nicer answer than the direction I was heading!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT X,Y,COUNT(1) AS[COUNT] FROM
(
 SELECT a_3 as x, a_4 as y FROM result
 ....
 UNION
 SELECT a_19 as x, a_20 as y FROM result
) x
GROUP BY X,Y
```